# C# custom control in debug and release configurations

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linker, custom-controls

I recently started learning how to create custom controls in C#, and I wasn't able to find any good explanation of how does it treat Debug and Release configurations.

Simplified version of my project looks like this:

```
MyProject
  |- CustomControl.cs
  |- Form.cs
```

`CustomControl.cs` is my control, and `Form.cs` is a form that contains instance of `CustomControl`. I added `CustomControl` to `Form` using design toolbox, and in order to be able to do so I had to right click on it, select "Choose Items" and manually point to assembly produced by my project : .../bin/**debug**/MyProject.exe .

Here is my question : If I selected Debug assembly, will it cause any problems in Release mode? I checked that it compiles and works, but does that mean that VS is smart enough to link to Release assembly, or it just still links to Debug assembly?

Comment: are you talking about taking a dll reference to your MyProject.exe ? Otherwise given that everything is in MyProject I do not see why you need to refer to the output exe from within itself

Comment: I had to point to MyProject.exe to see CustomControl in toolbox. Otherwise it didn't show up.

Comment: They should appear automatically. Undo what you did with your toolbox. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw694kde(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Codesleuth thanks for the link, it solved the issue. I don't know why, but I had `AutoToolboxPopulate` disabled. Now it shows in the toolbox and I don't have to select any assembly.

Comment: No problem! I'm actually going to post this as an answer to make sure this question is useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As per my comment*

Components should appear in the toolbox automatically. Undo what you did with your toolbox to add your custom control and have a look at this link: [Walkthrough: Automatically Populating the Toolbox with Custom Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw694kde%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

*Please see [OP's comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003894/c-sharp-custom-control-in-debug-and-release-configurations#comment21077025_15003894) for the solution details regarding `AutoToolboxPopulate`.*